# new facebook pixel, does event have to be within standard code for entire pixel?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using the new facebook pixel, they give the entire pixel code i.e:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
        n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
        document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '123459182912824234');
    fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
               src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12348712381712&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I have no problem adding that to the header of my site,

The problem is that I want to add the event tracking as well for example:

```
fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
```

But since my header is always the same on every page of my site I want to just put the event code within the body of the page itself.

Can I simply add only the event code in the body like so:

fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');

Or do I have to have the event code within the entire pixel code?

If it has to be within the entire code of the pixel, then I will have to detect which page I am on to change the event code which is a bit more of a pain then simply putting the event code on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test with the separate script in the body and it seems to work just fine.